# On equivalence of pairs of doubly periodic functions

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-functions

I am  self studying analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory.

I am struck on proving this theorem and I need help

Theorem is - Two pairs ( a, b) and ( c, d) are equivalent iff there exists a 2× 2 matrix
$$ 
      \begin{matrix} 
      p & q \\
      r & s\\
      \end{matrix}
$$
with integer entries and determinant of matrix equal + 1 or - 1  such that $ (c, d ) ^T $ = 
 $$ 
       \begin{matrix} 
         p & q \\
         r & s \\
         \end{matrix}
 $$
×  $ ( a, b)^T $ .

Definition- Two pairs of complex numbers ( a, b) and ( c, d) are called equivalent iff if they generate same lattice of periods.

Lattice of periods of (a,b) is set of all linear combinations of ax+by where a, b belongs from complex numbers such that a/b is complex number and x, y are integers.

Please give some hints . I am unable to prove any of the side.

Edit ---> I proved one side, assuming equivalence  I proved matrix exists.

But assuming such a matrix exists I have no clue how to prove equivalence . Please give some hint.

Comment: The inverse of the described matrix will also have integer entries.

Comment: @random  But i am asking --> assuming inverse with integer entries exists, then how to prove the two given pairs are equivalent ie how to prove lattice generated by (a, b) and (c, d) are equivalent?  Can you please give a hint or two.

Comment: The existence of the described matrix means that $c$ and $d$, and therefore the lattice that they generate, are part of the lattice generated by  $a$ and $b$. The existence of the inverse matrix implies that the lattice generated by $a$ and $b$ is a part of the lattice generated by $c$ and $d$.

Comment: @random thanks you very much